# Show that $len(a) − len(b) − 1 ≤ len(q) ≤ len(a) − len(b) + 1$ where len(a) is a bit length of integer a.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I was reading my Number theory book and can't seem to figure out this simple question.

**Some Background:**

For an integer a, we define its bit length, or simply, its length, which we denote by len(a), to be the number of bits in the binary representation of |a|;

more precisely,

$len(a)$ $:=$ $⌊log2|a|⌋+1$ $\quad if $   $a\not=0$,

$len(a)$ $:= 1$  $\quad   $ $\quad$           $if$  $a = 0$.

If $len(a) = l$, we say that a is an $l$-bit integer. Notice that if a is a positive, $l$-bit integer, then $log_2(a) < l ≤ log_2(a+1)$, or equivalently, $2^{l−1} ≤ a < 2^l$.

**My question:**

Let $a,b ∈ Z$ with $a ≥ b > 0$, and $let\quad q := ⌊a/b⌋$.

Show that $len(a) − len(b) − 1 ≤ len(q) ≤ len(a) − len(b) + 1$.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: multiply the following, then use the properties of $\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b} \right\rfloor\,$:

$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
2^{l−1} & \le a && \lt 2^l \\
2^{-m} & \lt \frac{1}{b} && \le 2^{-m+1}
\end{alignat}
$$